# jquery filtrify script, how to hide unrelated tags

Tags: jquery

I just tried out Filtrify jquery script - http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/

But I have one small problem that unfortunately I can't solve.

I would like to hide empty/not-related tags from filter menu

For example, in this demo - http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/movies.html If I select „Aaron Eckheart” from "main actors" filter one movie shows up.

Next, if I open „genre” filter, a lot of genres „Adventure, Animation, Biography” are not related to „Aaron Eckheart” at this point. And I think it would be great to hide them, but I’m not sure how to do that.

I was thinking that I should use `.addClass("ft-hidden")` if tag count is 0. I tried some light experimenting after looking through jquery code, but at the moment I just don't have the knowledge :(

Could you please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with this library, but purely from hacking through the console, you could probably stab this somewhere, most probably in its `callback` (See http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/query.html)

```
$('.ft-label').parent()
    .find('li[data-count=0]').hide().end()
    .find(':not(li[data-count=0])').show().end();
```

As a simple test, visit the link you mentioned (http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/movies.html), run the following code in your browser console to duck-punch the original demo code, and see if the result is what you want

```
$(function() {
    $.filtrify("container", "placeHolder", {
        callback: function ( query, match, mismatch ) {
            $('.ft-label').parent()
                .find('li[data-count=0]').hide().end()
                .find(':not(li[data-count=0])').show().end();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you!

This is exactly what I wanted.